# Use exported value in setup of Vue Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

In a plain js file the code looks like

```
export default async function exportData() {
  const { data } = await store
      .dispatch('fetchData')

  const { bookings } = data
  const booking = bookings.length ? bookings[0]._id : ''

  const event = {
    bookingID: booking
  }

  // other methods and variables

  return {
    .....
  }
}
```

inside the vue file

```
import exportData from './exportData'
export default {
  setup() {
    const {
      fetchEvents,
      isEventActive,
    } = exportData()
    fetchEvents()
  }
}
```

the problem is in vue components the values from exportData gets undefined, gets error fetchEvents is not a function when the export is asynchronous. works well if not asynchronous. what is the workaround here??

Answer (score 1):

You can try to declare fetchEvents,isEventActive methods in plan js file without wrapping it inside any function

```
const fetchEvents = () => {
   //body
};

const isEventActive = () => {
     //body
};
```

and export them as

```
export {fetchEvents, isEventActive};
```

now use them

```
import {fetchEvents,isEventActive} from 'path-to-js-file'
export default {
  setup() {
    fetchEvents()
    isEventActive()
  }
}
```

Comment: not feasible in my case. i have many variables and methods in that export and there are some dependency. the problem is with asynchronous call. if i remove async, the code works.

Comment: No asynchronous methods also works also works fine here you just have to call them asyncronously

Comment: but it defeats my async await.. i need to await to complete the store dispatch call.

Comment: Ok you may know what's better for your code